# SLSQP Error: length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, minimization

Hi I am working with both the SLSQP solver on python and diffev2 which is part of the mystic package.

For multiple parameters the format shown below works:

```
bnds = ((0, 1e3), (0, 1e-4))
optimize.minimize(Error, [1e-8, 1e-7], args=(E, Bt, L, dt, TotT, nz, Co, Exmatrix), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds)
```

I want to optimize only one parameter and that is when I run into the error: SLSQP Error: the length of bounds is not compatible with that of x0.
I use the syntax shown below:

```
bnds = ((1e-9, 1e-2))
optimize.minimize(Error, [1e-8], args=(U, E, Bt, L, dt, TotT, nz, Co, Exmatrix), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds)
```

I am not sure what is wrong, as I have only one tuple pair in the bnds variable and one guess, not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for SLSQP but for the diffev2 solver from mystic package, it seems to be taking parameter as a sequence and producing an error inside my code saying: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'. The non integer is another parameter of value 0.5 that is multiplied with the optimized parameter. 
. I did not think of the `minimize_scalar` as I had just been using SLSQP with multi variables and only recently reduced the variable to one.

Comment: But that's not related to the question above. If the answer solves that, mark it as such and if you got a new problem, ask a new question with details! (and tag it correctly; here you missed scipy for example which is rather relevant). ```can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'.``` usually is something like: you used lists, where numpy.arrays where expected (as ```[0,1,2] * 0.2``` does not work for lists; while it does for numpy).

Answer (score 4):

Straight from python's [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

> The trailing comma is required only to create a single tuple (a.k.a. a singleton); it is optional in all other cases. A single expression without a trailing comma doesn’t create a tuple, but rather yields the value of that expression. (To create an empty tuple, use an empty pair of parentheses: ().)

Working alternatives:

```
bnds = ((1e-9, 1e-2),)
bnds = [(1e-9, 1e-2)]
```

[Internally](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a03fd3f015503802bf4246877115cc07c9a4afb5/scipy/optimize/slsqp.py#L338), this happens:

```
bnds = ((1e-9, 1e-2))
np.array(bnds, float).shape
# (2,)

bnds = ((1e-9, 1e-2),)
np.array(bnds, float).shape
# (1, 2)

# and then N is compared to the size of the first dimension (2 vs. 1)
```

(And make sure you got a reason not to use `minimize_scalar`)

Comment: Thank you, that worked fine for the SLSQP. I will try the `minimize_scalar` function as well. I have been trying the diffev2 global solver for some of my other work, and when I try this syntax, for some reason, it seems to read my parameter as a sequence. Will investigate further and perhaps post another comment.